# How do I rewrite URL to drop file extension for pdf on github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

Imagine my website is hosted on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) and has a custom domain `website.com`. I can access a pdf at `website.com/mypdf.pdf`

Is there a way where I can make it work at `website.com/mypdf`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, if you are using static website hosted by a 3rd party like GitHub pages, you don't really get a lot of control over http server. I would tentatively say you cannot control URL rewrite rules on GitHub.

What you could potentially do instead is to host a page with a bit of JavaScript that would start the download on a given event (button click, page load, etc) this way you could mask your actual download URL with this html page (that by convention comes with no file extension)

**UPD:** and surely enough someone's been doing it already: http://lea.verou.me/2016/11/url-rewriting-with-github-pages/. The post is going on about having nice urls, but I believe file downloads implementation can be implemented similarly

Answer (score -2):

Yes you should make your website with MVC structure. Make a controller and in Index action load pdf file.
Then on action calling your pdf will be loaded like that:
Students/AllResult etc

Comment: I suspect you are assuming a few things about OP's setup. I am no github pages expert, but I would say, your suggestion will not apply to static websites (which I believe github pages are)

Comment: exactly @timur , is what I'm asking possible on a straight static site without the use of a plugin.